# Safari, MVC3 ajax form submit

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, jquery, safari, form-submit

I have a form that submits just fine in FF, IE 8, IE 9, chrome.

In safari (windows), it submits but my model is empty. This behavior is only on my dev and prod site, not local development. Local development works normal. What am i doing wrong here?

Form:

```
<form action="/NetSite/Applications/ElectronicFileTransfer" id="TransfersSearchForm" method="post">        
    <table class="siteTable">
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <th style="width: 20%;">FICE</th>
                    <td style="width: 80%;"><input id="Criteria_Fice" maxlength="6" name="Criteria.Fice" size="6" type="text" value="" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th>Source Email</th>
                    <td><input id="Criteria_SourceEmail" maxlength="40" name="Criteria.SourceEmail" size="25" type="text" value="" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th>Target Email</th>
                    <td><input id="Criteria_TargetEmail" maxlength="100" name="Criteria.TargetEmail" size="25" type="text" value="" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th>Upload From Date</th>
                    <td>

            <input class="datePicker" data-val="true" data-val-date="Invalid date specified. Date should be like MM/DD/YYYY." id="Criteria_FromDate" maxlength="12" name="Criteria.FromDate" size="12" type="text" value="" />

                        <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="Criteria.FromDate" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th>Upload To Date</th>
                    <td>

            <input class="datePicker" data-val="true" data-val-date="Invalid date specified. Date should be like MM/DD/YYYY." id="Criteria_ToDate" maxlength="12" name="Criteria.ToDate" size="12" type="text" value="" />

                        <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="Criteria.ToDate" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th class="empty"></th>
                    <td>
                        <button type="submit" title="Search" id="SubmitButton" class="gradientbutton gradientsmall gradientorange">Search</button>&nbsp;
                        <button type="button" title="Clear" id="ClearButton" class="gradientbutton gradientsmall gradientorange">Reset</button>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
</form>
```

JS submit method called by the event:

```
searchFormSubmit: function ($form, currentForm) {
        if ($form.valid()) {
            var $button = $("#" + FileTransferHome._enum.SubmitButton);
            var $searchResults = $("#" + FileTransferHome._enum.SearchResultsDivId);

            jMessage("Processing request...", $button, true, false);
            $.ajax({
                cache: false,
                url: currentForm.action,
                type: currentForm.method,
                data: $form.serialize(),
                error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                    jMessageHide();
                    $searchResults.html(xhr.responseText).addClass(JSGlobalVars.MessageBoxError).fadeIn('slow');
                },
                success: function (result) {
                    jMessageHide();
                    $searchResults.removeClass(JSGlobalVars.MessageBoxError).html(result).fadeIn('slow');
                    location.hash = "SEARCHRESULTS";
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

Action:

I have an else block in there that i have put in just to test this case and it executes rather than the main block.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(ElectronicFileTransferHomeViewModel model)
{
    ... actions...
}
```

[image]

Comment: Where do you have an `else` bock? Looks like your Safari browser is configured with a different culture than your web server and you are having problems with the datetime formats.

Comment: I have added an image showing all nulls even when i have items selected. I cleared cache and was able to replicate this on my local development also.

Comment: @learning:Did you resolve the problem? I have the same issue too, only in safari browser.

Comment: I'm having the same problem... MVC forms work everywhere except from Safari to a intranet server; the application responds as if it is getting none of the form values. *BUT* if Safari uses Fiddler2 as a proxy it works!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This in as internal app and behind windows login. Safari has a non issue with with windows authentication. 
A work around that seems to be working for us (although not ideal) is to put Safari in Private browsing mode.